# Parsing a date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I could get the year, month (0 based) and day from `'03/05/2013'`

If so, how?

Thanks

Is there a safe way to do it that can check if it is in the correct format?

Comment: Relevant: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: The `Date` constructor might not like your format, but regexes are always available; what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, but http://bit.ly/15y49gj

Comment: Is that the third of may, ar the fifth of march? I can only guess you mean the yesterday's date of the fifth of march.

Comment: @sweetamylase that was rude

Comment: What would the regular expression for mm/dd/yyyy be?

Comment: Want some sugar? http://sugarjs.com/dates

Comment: @JanDvorak why rude? This is true that a lot of people just post another question on SO instead of trying to find an answer themself.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's a basic question that a quick google could find. The user didn't attempt to try that first, but expects people to give him a direct answer.

Comment: @sweetamylase I agree with that. A link to google + downvote would still be better than a link to LMGTFY.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `Date.parse` method which parses a Date string and returns its timestamp, so you can call `new Date()`.

Something like this:

```
new Date(Date.parse('03/06/2013'))
```

Comment: How do I know if it failed?

Comment: you could also just do `new Date('03/06/2013')`...but the points above still stand.... is that March 6th or June 3rd?

Comment: March 6. In the same way you use '.' (instead of ',') when calling parseFloat.

Comment: And about validation, I think you need some RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy is using the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function, i think:

```
var date = "03/05/2013";
var dateParts = date.split("/");

var day = dateParts[0];
var month = dateParts[1];
var year = dateParts[2];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7ma2/1/

Comment: Close, but you have to swap `day` and `month` (month/day/year) if my understanding is correct. It's a weird format, I know.

Comment: Well, you could check the length of the array dateParts: dateParts.length() which should return 3